# Split a PHP string when delimiter contains more that one character

Tags: php

I have a string in PHP which is as follows.
I want to split it using preg_split.

The string is "ashhsa://xyzasa".

How do I split it where the delimiter contains more than one character?
I should get **ashhsa** and **xyzasa** in the output array.

Note : This is different than splitting a string with multiple delimiters.

Comment: What have you tried? Straight forward `://` [seems to work](http://codepad.org/dOYU1Rqq)

Comment: Just :// does not work.

Comment: http://codepad.org/MvAMN830 no regular exresssion needed

Comment: @tushR yes it does ,see both our code pad examples

Comment: I was using preg_split. That's why it did not work with just ://

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no regular expression needed, explode will work just fine:

```
var_dump( explode('://', 'ashhsa://xyzasa') );


array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "ashhsa"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "xyzasa"
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/MvAMN830

it will be faster than `preg_split()` not that it should be significant.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the delimiter that you want. You have to escape the / but it's not complicated.

```
$string = "ashhsa://xyzasa";
$parts = preg_split('/:\/\//', $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_dump($parts);
```